# How to right-align menu in bootstrap navbar

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to get the  element with "navbar-right" to float over to the right but couldn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #8C4332;">
            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-left" href="#">
                <img src="./img/Leaf_icon.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
                Singapore Ecological History Map
            </a>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class=" nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p?starter=Bootstrap%20%2B%20FontAwesome

Answer (score 0):

In the description for what you’re trying to accomplish, you say you want to “get the element with ‘navbar-right’ to float over to the left but couldn't,” but do you mean *right* and not *left*?

If you want the menu items for the three links to be on the left, you could use:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #8C4332;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./img/Leaf_icon.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        Singapore Ecological History Map</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

*This is from the [Bootstrap example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/#supported-content).*
If you want the menu items for the three links to be on the left, you just need to add `ml-auto` to the unordered list:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #8C4332;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./img/Leaf_icon.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        Singapore Ecological History Map</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Starting with the code from Bootstrap gives you the hamburger icon that will show and hide the menu on mobile devices.

Comment: I tried both but it still doesn't work; I am not entirely sure why. I added your code but it still aligns to the left. https://www.codeply.com/p/FqSJPuf0mY

Comment: Try adding to your navbar-right class this property and value:
    flex-flow: row-reverse;

Comment: That’s strange that the code’s not working for you. I opened your Codeply, which has the three link items on the left, next to …Map and I changed the line `<ul class="navbar-nav">` to `<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">`. I *ran* the changed version and the three link items shifted to the far right side of the navbar. I may not be understanding what it is you’re looking for if ml-auto doesn’t do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #8C4332;">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="./img/Leaf_icon.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        Singapore Ecological History Map
    </a>
        
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-pills nav-fill btn-group">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/VW38uSsWQO

**Changes I made...**

- add "justify-content-end" class at collapse div
- add the collapse responsive hamburguer
- delete nav-right from ul tag

**Explanation**
justify-content-end is a flexbox class that BS4 implemented. It is great because allows you to position this code wher you want: left (justify-content-start), center (justify-content-center) or right.
But you have to apply this by blocks. For this reason I used into div tag which involves all menu this you want to move.
I hope it works for you.